# how to manage sys.path globally in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a bunch of unittests that import stuff not from `/python2.7/site-packages/` but from a completely different directory. So what I do is do some monkey-patching in each test file with `sys.path.append` to make my Python see what I need.

Is there a way to append `sys.path` globally for the whole Pycharm project without bothering with each and every file?

UPDATE:
setting default working directory doesn't help. For example, if I set the working directory to `/Users/1111/_projects/_empty_dir/` like so:

[image: screenshot]

and then run this

```
import sys
for p in sys.path: print p
```

what I see is this

```
/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/blesk/bin/python /Users/1111/_projects/_testing_pycharm/importer.py
/Users/1111/_projects/_testing_pycharm
/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/blesk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.9.0-py2.7.egg
/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/blesk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/parse-1.6.6-py2.7.egg
/Users/1111/_projects/_testing_pycharm
/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/blesk/lib/python27.zip
/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/blesk/lib/python2.7
/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/blesk/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/blesk/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/blesk/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/blesk/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/blesk/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/blesk/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/blesk/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Process finished with exit code 0
```

and there is no `/Users/1111/_projects/_empty_dir/` on `sys.path`.

Answer (score 25):

This is one fairly easy, follow this path:

1. settings
2. project: `<your project name>`
3. project interpreter
4. select the interpreter you want to update `sys.path` for
   [image]
5. find the bottom right icon, `'show paths for the selected interpreter'`
6. add the folder to the list of paths.

Comment: Between steps 3 & 4 you should have "click on `show all`"

Comment: It works in PyCharm but it does not work in terminal when I `source venv/bin/activate`. `sys.path` does not include the directories I add in pycharm.

Answer (score 13):

There is now a better way to do it. You can `Mark Directory as` as `Sources root`. This option will appear in the bottom when you right click on any directory in Project.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

I am on a Mac, using PyCharm 4.5.1 Professional Edition. Your platform and version may be a bit different, but if you make sure you are on the latest version, it should work.

**EDIT:** I've updated this answer and uploaded a new screenshot.

What you want is to set the working directory **and** the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

The working directory sets the directory to be used by the running task. and the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable adds directories to `sys.path`

Go to `Run` -> `Edit Configurations`

In the dialog box that comes up, navigate to `Defaults` -> `Python tests` -> `Unittests`

Set your working directory and your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and you are all set. Your tests will be automatically run from that working directory and have the sys.path that you want. You can include multiple paths in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable if you separate them with a colon `:`

For example:

```
PYTHONPATH=/path/to/dir:/path/to/other/dir
```

If you already have some existing test configurations, you may want to delete them so that they get re-created when you run tests or set the working directory and `PYTHONPATH` for each of them. You can delete them from the same dialog window

`Run` -> `Edit Configurations` then expand `Python Tests` to see your existing test configurations

If you don't want to delete your existing test configurations, just specify the working directory for each existing test configuration individually.

[image]

Comment: doesnt help, see my comment above

Answer (score 0):

Config location in new layout of PyCharm 2023.3.2

[image]